# Versioning document changes in Vespa

Tags: vespa, database-versioning

I would like to allow for versioning of text in Vespa. If a user changes certain fields over time the changes would be tracked and versions could be restored.

I imagine a solution running in parallel to Vespa would be the way to go, with version numbers being stored in the vespa doc as unindexed data.

Any recommendations on a solution to use to do this? Something like http://jsonpatch.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just store each version as a separate document by including the version in the document id.